# Why does putting dots at the end of a file name cause python to think that the file exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filepath

Suppose that in the current working directory you have a file, named "`blabarfoo`" There is no file extension at the end of the filename, such as "`.txt`" or "`.mp3`" Consider the following 3 lines of code:

```
import os
import pathlib
path1 = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) / "blahbarfoo"
```

I expect the following line of code to return true, and it does:

```
pathlib.Path(path1).exists()
```

However, I am surprised to find that the following call to `exists()` also returns true:

```
path2 = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) / "blahbarfoo........"
pathlib.Path(path1).exists()
```

Note that there is no file named `blahbarfoo........`

Can someone explain to me why dots at the end of the path do not effect anything?
More code demonstrating the phenomenon is shown below:

```
import os
import pathlib

def get_path_stats(xpath):
    stats = '\n'.join([str(x[0]).ljust(10) + str(x[1]) for x in [
        ("*"* 60, ""),
        ("path:", xpath),
        ['is_file:', pathlib.Path(xpath).is_file()],
        ["exists:",  pathlib.Path(xpath).exists()],
        ["is dir:", pathlib.Path(xpath).is_dir()],
        ("*"* 60, ""),
    ]])
    return stats

p1 = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) / "blahb"
p2 = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) / "blahbarfoo"
p3 = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) //"blahbarfoo."
p4 = pathlib.Path(os.getcwd()) / "blahbarfoo........"

ps = [p1, p2, p3, p4]

for p in ps:
   status = get_path_stats(p)
   print(status)
```

We have the following output:

```
************************************************************
path:     D:\FILE_MGMT_PYTHON\blahb
is_file:  False
exists:   False
is dir:   False
************************************************************
************************************************************
path:     D:\FILE_MGMT_PYTHON\blahbarfoo
is_file:  True
exists:   True
is dir:   False
************************************************************
************************************************************
path:     D:\FILE_MGMT_PYTHON\blahbarfoo.
is_file:  True
exists:   True
is dir:   False
************************************************************
************************************************************
path:     D:\FILE_MGMT_PYTHON\blahbarfoo........
is_file:  True
exists:   True
is dir:   False
************************************************************
```

I wondered if `.` might match zero or more characters, but python says that the file `blahb.` does not exist:

```
************************************************************
path:     D:\FILE_MGMT_PYTHON\blahb.
is_file:  False
exists:   False
is dir:   False
************************************************************
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to Python, but to the filesystem and how the OS handles it.

It will return `False` on pretty much every system other than the Windows-based ones.

If you open a command line, go in that directory and type `dir blahbarfoo`, it will list the file, but `dir blahbarfoo.*` will not. `dir blahbarfoo.` will list the file.

The "concept" (however debatable) is that the file has no extension, so if you search for that name with any extension it will not be listed (any extension != no extension).

But if you do specify a `.`, then you're simply saying "no extension" again and it will be listed. Since all those dots are no extension (you cannot have a `...` extension), they're not considered and the file is listed.

This however is different if you use the Windows UI and rename a file from there.

Both `pathlib` and `os.path` use the system call `stat` to determine if a file exists, and a system call is just that: it depends on the system (for details you might want to look up the differences between FAT, NTFS and how they're supported in the various versions of Windows).